# Developer Jobs Directory doesn't look good when using dark mode

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface, dark-mode

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/developer-jobs) looks bad when using dark mode. (The titles don't have enough contrast.)

[image: screenshot of the page]

Comment: Sorry for the lack of red circles